# mongodb query or with $ne condition

Tags: mongodb

My query with or:

```
"$or": [

                    {
                        "store": id, 
                        "status": {"$ne": pending}
                    },
                    {
                        "store": id, 
                        "status": pending,
                        "stage": {"$ne": active}
                    }
]
```

is it possible to have more simple query with same results as above ?

Comment: `{ store: id, $or: [ { "status": { "$ne": pending },  "stage": { "$ne": active } } ] }`

Comment: Kinda like this `(A and B) or (A and ~B and C) =  A and (B or C)`

Comment: Where `A` is `"store": id`, `B` is `"status": {"$ne": pending}` and `C` is `"stage": {"$ne": active}`

Comment: thanks,

but i tried and the result not same as above,

actually i was think if theres a way to do something like

 get record for store "xxx", exclude (status "pending"  and stage "$ne" active )